# Asp net core How to add endpoint dynamicly after startup

Tags: asp.net-core

Is it possible to add new enpoint dynamicly after startup executed in AspNetCore?

Any suggestions how would you solve this particular problem which is simplified.

We are having a admin controller which can manage how many chat rooms are open.
Each chat room has its own WebSocket or Hub if singalr which is registered to his own endpoint ("/hub1", "/hub2", etc.).
So admin connects to controller calls action OpenChatRoom("/Hub3") in which it would need to registers new
endpoint "hub3" which uses websocket handler/middelware in runtime and does not need to restart asp net core app.

Comment: What's the benefit of having a hub for each chatroom?

Comment: In my opinion, there is no need to start so many hubs, you could use signlar's group feature. The hub1 will be the group name, then you could send the message in that group. Create so many hub is not a good choice.